# Change the color of nodes on double click in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, attributes, double-click

I want the color of node to change on double click. i.e. On the first double click, it would turn black but on re-double clicking it, it would turn back to its original color. I am able to make it turn black on the first double click, but I'm not able to make it turn back to its original color.  Thanks in advance and here is my code.

```
var gnodes = svg.selectAll('g.gnode')
                .data(graph.nodes)
                .enter()
                .append('g')
                .classed('gnode', true);

var node = gnodes.append("circle")
                 .attr("class", "node")
                 .attr("r", 5)
                 .style("fill", function(d) {return d.colr; })
                 .on('dblclick', function (d)
                 {
                         if (d3.select(this).style("fill") != "black")
                            {
                                d3.select(this).style("fill", "black");
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                d3.select(this).style("fill", function(d){return d.colr;});
                            }
                })
                .call(force.drag);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're having here is actually really tricky to spot.

You are checking whether the `fill` style is equal to the string `"black"`. The problem is, many browsers (including Chrome and FF) reformat color names to RGB strings. So, when you set the fill to `"black"`, it is converted to the RGB string `"rgb(0, 0, 0)"`. So actually, calling  `d3.select(this).style("fill")` will return this rgb string rather than the color name, ensuring that the `else` branch of your code never runs.

You can avoid having to check the current state of your fill as a style string by using `selection.each` to store each circle's state as a boolean value and then register its double-click handler, which toggles the boolean and then branches based on its value. Try this:

```
var node = gnodes.append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", function(d) {return d.colr; })
  .each(function() {
    var sel = d3.select(this);
    var state = false;
    sel.on('dblclick', function() {
      state = !state;
      if (state) {
        sel.style('fill', 'black');
      } else {
        sel.style('fill', function(d) { return d.colr; });
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me because all nodes become black rather than just the double clicked one.

Comment: Ah, `gnodes` is an enter selection isn't it. Okay I updated the answer to use `selection.each` to do the same thing, but for each circle.

Comment: Works! Thank you so much! That's a nice way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

One way to handle this is via CSS:

```
.doubled { fill: black !important; }
```

Then toggle this CSS class in your dblclick function:

```
d3.selectAll(".node")
  .on("dblclick", function() {
    var c = d3.select(this).classed("doubled");
    d3.select(this).classed("doubled", !c);
  })
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/qAHC2/829/

Comment: Looks like I'm making some mistake, because this doesn't work despite adding the CSS class. The colors don't change at all.